# pod install CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER

Tags: flutter, pod-install

Hi I ran the podintall command and I'm getting these errors:

[!] The `ImageNotification [Debug]` target overrides the `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ImageNotification/Pods-ImageNotification.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `ImageNotification [Release]` target overrides the `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ImageNotification/Pods-ImageNotification.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `ImageNotification [Profile]` target overrides the `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ImageNotification/Pods-ImageNotification.profile.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

this is my podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
end
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      end
    end
  end

  # installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  #   flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  # end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

how can I solve this problem?
Thanks for your help